# Convert this ISO-8601 formatted string to java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, iso8601, datetime-parsing

I have a string which is supposed to be in ISO 8601 format.  An example value of the string is:

```
"2017-01-12T07:12:15-0500"
```

I've been trying to parse this in a number of ways.  I've tried both `LocalDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`.  All of these have failed:

```
OffsetDateTime ot = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-01-12T07:12:15-0500");
OffsetDateTime ot = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-01-12T07:12:15-0500", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

LocalDateTime lt = LocalDateTime .parse("2017-01-12T07:12:15-0500");
LocalDateTime lt = LocalDateTime .parse("2017-01-12T07:12:15-0500", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

The exception is always

```
Text '2017-01-12T07:12:15-0500' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
```

It seems to not like the `0500` part.  I thought this was a valid format for an ISO 8601 date.  If it's not, what's the proper way to parse this string?

Comment: Note that because you have hyphens and colons in the main part of your string, you should also have a colon in the offset `-05:00` to be strictly compliant with the ISO-8601 extended format.  You can probably adjust the parsing code to accommodate, but it is not strictly compliant.  ISO-8601 allows for basic and extended forms, but not to mix parts of each.